# htaccess .zip url rewrite from /*.zip to /key/*.zip

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Currently I have some zip files stored in the http root of my php/apache web server.

Currently I can access the files using this:

```
http://example.com/filename.zip
```

However, I want to "protect" the access to this files, and they should only be accessible using something like:

```
http://example.com/key/filename.zip
```

Could someone help me to create a rewrite rule to do this?

The key is a fixed string. It will be hardcoded in `.htaccess` rules.

---

When the user accesses the following URL:

```
http://example.com/key/filename.zip
```

He should be able to download the zip file.

---

When the user accesses the following URL:

```
http://example.com/filename.zip
```

He should not be able to download the zip file. He should receive an http error.

---

My code so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^key/(\w+).zip $1.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code should already serve `/filename.zip` when accessing `/key/filename.zip` (although it should be tidied a bit).

To block direct requests to `/filename.zip`, you can do something like the following before your existing directive:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?\w+\.zip$ - [F]
```

This blocks (403 Forbidden) *all* direct requests for URLs of the form `/filename.zip` (in the document root), regardless of whether it maps to an existing file or not.

Alternatively, to send a 404 instead, change the `F` flag to `R=404`.

So, in summary:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block direct requests to /<filename>.zip
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?\w+\.zip$ - [R=404]

# Internally rewrite /key/<filename>.zip to /<filename>.zip
RewriteRule ^/?key/(\w+)\.zip /$1.zip [L]
```

Remember to backslash escape the dot to match a literal dot.

Note that this unconditionally rewrites all requests for `/key/<filename>.zip` to `/<filename>.zip`, regardless of whether `/<filename>.zip` exists or not. You'll just get a 404 if it doesn't.

The `L` flag may be required if you have other directives that follow.

I've modified the directives so they will work in the server config (as well as `.htaccess`).